# Possible to automatically set value in a column depending on other values from same row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say my row have columns: A, B, and AB

If I were to INSERT value 5 for column A and value 2 for column B, is it possible for MySQL or something to automatically take these values and do something with it, such as multiply and store it into a specific column, such as AB?

My basic goal is to get (using SQL query) the top 5 values in the table based on the multiplication of A and B.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , yes , yes , yes ,yes , yes

just do this if you want insert them like that.

```
    Insert into table (column_ab) values (a * b)
```

or just  when you select do like that

```
   select a , b , a*b as multip from your_table Order by multip desc LIMIT 5
```

this you will get multiplied values of a and b and top 5 .

Comment: The select part is exactly what I am looking for!  Thanks for the swift answer!

Answer (score 3):

One solution to make a column automatically calculate a column based on other columns is to use a trigger:

```
mysql> DELIMITER !

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER calc_ab_ins BEFORE INSERT ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.ab = NEW.a * NEW.b;
END !

mysql> CREATE TRIGGER calc_ab_upd BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  SET NEW.ab = NEW.a * NEW.b;
END !

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into the columns of a and b just insert the multiplication of the two into the third column like this.

```
INSERT INTO Sample (a, b, ab) VALUES (5, 10, 5*10);
```

[SQL Fiddle of it in action here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0fb3e/1)